# cookie laravel s

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have a `like` field in my model, now I want to make the functionality of adding a like using Cookie. For example, we have an article ID, we check in cookies, if there is no data, then we add like and set the time for 10 hours, for example, and so on, 10 hours pass, we check and again we can add like and set this time again. If the data is already there, then we do not add like and do not update the time.

Can anyone see some examples of this? Or where to start and how to implement it?

I read the documentation but did not quite understand how it should work

Let's get a value with a like field

```
$likes = Request::cookie('like');
```

Choosing the time

```
$minutes = 600;
```

And what's next, how can I make a check to add a like?

Comment: (sending email to: "
<a data-first="test" data-second="test.com" class="js-combaine-email">test@test.com</a>
" )." Im not a pro by any means but this has a space before the end parentheses in the string

Answer (score 2):

Use Replace function on the string and replace " )." with ")."

Comment: looking at the documentation of preg_replace your passed argument and pattern look wrong.
Try this `preg_replace('/\s+\)./', ').', string_to_replace)`

Comment: Accidently posted comment too soon, edited my first comment.
You can always use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to create/debug/test your regex.
Documentation [php preg-replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Odd, I tested it in a [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d04856a0d51ef8722f606e310de0a19f2693c01b) without issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238614/discussion-between-benjamin-and-meow).